# onCall function in Firebase Functions results in Unhandled Rejection Error in Firebase Function Logs

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

By following the Firebase Docs and Stripe API Docs, I have created a function that creates a charge from a token that is passed. This function is setup with Firebases onCall function to be able to call it directly from my app.

Sadly, when you call the function, Stripe returns an error, though the function doesn't seem to send that to the client as my client thinks it was a success.

**Firebase Function in index.ts**

```
export const oneTimeCharge = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
  stripe.charges.create({
    amount: data.amount,
    currency: data.currency,
    source: data.source,
    description: data.description
  }).then((charge) => {
    return {'charge':charge};
  }).catch((error) => {
    throw new functions.https.HttpsError('unknown', 'Something went wrong!', error);
  })
});
```

When I call this function, the Firebase Functions Logs show the two following errors. This leads me to believe that my **functions.https.HttpsError** is not correct.

**Error 1**

```
Unhandled rejection
```

**Error 2**

```
Error: Something went wrong!
at stripe.charges.create.then.catch (/srv/lib/index.js:37:15)
at <anonymous>
at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:229:7)
```

and my service function in Angular returns it as a success. What am I missing or doing wrong? I feel like I've googled for hours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Cloud Functions, you are required to return a promise that resolves when all the asynchronous works is complete.  For callable type functions, that promise must resolve with the data to send to the client.  Right now, your function is returning nothing from the top level function.  What you should try, at a minimum, is returning the promise returned from `stripe.charges.create(...).then(...).catch(...)`:

```
return stripe.charges.create(...)
    ...
```

Please read carefully the [documentation for callables](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable) to make sure you understand your obligations, and also make sure that you fully understand how promises work, otherwise things won't work the way you expect.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation of your answer and the time taken to even include a link. I’ll give it a shot! Thank you!